# Why does getChildHtml() display my block but getChildHtml() doesn't?

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks

I can't figure why my block is not displayed as expected. Here what i've done to debug this. First of all my layout:

```
<layout>
<vendor_contest_contest_index translate="label" module="vendor_contest">
    <label>Contests list</label>
    <update handle="page_one_column" />
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="vendor_contest/contest_list" name="contest_list" template="vendor_contest/contest/list.phtml" />
    </reference>
</vendor_contest_contest_index>
<vendor_contest_contest_view translate="label" module="vendor_contest">
    <label>Contest view page</label>
    <update handle="page_one_column" />
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="vendor_contest/contest_view" name="contest_view" template="vendor_contest/contest/view.phtml" >
            <block type="vendor_contest/contest_content" name="contest_content" template="vendor_contest/contest/content.phtml" />
            <block type="vendor_contest/contest_answer_list" name="contest.answer_list" as="contest_answers" template="vendor_contest/contest/answer/list.phtml" />
            <block type="vendor_contest/contest_answer_answered" name="contest.answer_answered" as="contest_answered" template="vendor_contest/contest/answer/answered.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</vendor_contest_contest_view>
</layout>
```

Here is the contest_view block :

```
public function getAnswersListView()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('contest.answer_list');
}

public function getAlreadyAnsweredView()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('contest.answer_answered');
}

public function hasCustomerAnswered()
{
    $answered = false;
    $contest = $this->getCurrentContest();
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('vendor_contest/participation')->getCollection();
    $collection
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
            ->addFieldToFilter('contest_id', $contest->getId())
            ->load();
    if (count($collection)) {
        $answered = true;
    }
    return $answered;
}
```

And my view.phtml

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('contest_content');
if ($this->hasCustomerAnswered()) {
     echo $this->getAlreadyAnsweredView();
} else {
    echo $this->getAnswersListView();
}
```

Here only the block contest_content is diplsayed. If i change the first line to

```
echo $this->getChildHtml();
```

All my blocks are displayed. That means there is no error in my block code, i guess. Both my system.log and error.log are empty.

If needed i can provide more files. Just tell me which one you'd like to see.

On my side i tried to debug this way :
i went to

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
```

and i dumped $childName in it.

```
string(15) "contest_content" string(19) "contest.answer_list" string(23) "contest.answer_answered"
```

And my three blocks are effectively displayed below.

I didnt manage to understand deeper why my block aren't displayed with the above snippets of code.

Thanks you all who'll take time to read this.

EDIT : here's my Content.php

```
<?php

class Vendor_Contest_Block_Contest_Content extends Vendor_Contest_Block_Contest_View
{

}
```

Notice the extends. Since basically block Content doesnt need anything more than View it felt right to me to extends Contest_View.

Comment: Could you post the content of your vendor_contest/contest_content block please ?

Comment: @DigitalPianism i added it.

Comment: What happens if you make this block extend Mage_Core_Block_Template instead ?

Comment: I first had an error Fatal error: Call to a member function getTitle(). So i copied the needed method from View.php to Content.php. Now it does display the content Block only as it did before.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment. Did it fix the problem ?

Comment: No it didnt. I'll try to be more clear. As you can see in my layout i have 3 blocks depending of contest_view. When i call echo $this->getChildHtml('contest_content'); from my view.phtml the block is rendered. BUT when i do echo $this->getAnswersListView(); or echo $this->getAlreadyAnsweredView(); those blocks ARE NOT rendered. But a call to getChildHtml(); render them all. Does it make more sense to you ?

Comment: Yes, clearer. Change your block name from contest.answer_list to answer_list in both your layout and your block function. Do the same for the contest.answer_answered block. I reckon the name does not match Magento standards.

Comment: OK i got this fixed thanks to your help. It wasnt about the block_name though. getChildHtml() expect an alias and not the name of the block, if expected. I'm not sure then why it is called "blockName" in Core... Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to the help provided by [@Digital Pianism](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2380/digital-pianism) in the comments I noticed `getChildHtml()` expects to be given an ALIAS block and not its name (if it exists). Don't be fooled by the variable name `$childName` in the core if you have to go through it.